# SSRS 2008r2 Reply To

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, sender

We set up a data subscription in SSRS, which we would like to have a specific sender address different from the SMTP address that is set up.

The subscription does not pick up the "Reply To" address for the report as the sender, defaulting to the SMTP address.  How can be have it use the "Reply To" address?

Also, the SMTP address is set up as **Our Company Name**   but all that comes through is "noreply" as that is the Exchange Acount.  Is there a way for **Our Company Name** to come through as the sender -- in the event we can't get "Reply To" to show on the subscribed reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the sender email address for individual subscriptions as this is set in Reporting Services configuration for the whole report server instance.

You should be able to add a "friendly name" to the Sender Address in Reporting Services configuration. Just enter the email address as:

```
"Our Company" address@ourcompany.com
```